# weird display exporting sql to excel sheet

Tags: coldfusion, export-to-excel, clob, cfquery

I am trying to export a query result to excel sheet. But whenever i have clob, it displays something like this [C@25c4828b.

the code is below.

```
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#FilePath#" overwrite="true" 
query="getinfo" >
```

the query is simple.

```
select * from my table
```

Comment: Have you enabled Clob retrieval for your datasource?

Comment: it is enabled. on the web page it is displaying correclty

Comment: Which dbms you using?

Comment: oracle sql. I think it is something related to cfspread sheet. I dumped the query it's showing correctly.

Comment: Could be... I don't use oracle. What happens if you cast the column as a string or varchar?

Comment: it works using cast. But the column value is way more than 4000

Comment: Any difference using functions like SpreadsheetAddRows, SpreadsheetSetCell, etc... instead of cfspreadsheet?

Comment: tried those too. but those ones have limits on max cell length so i got errors.

Comment: Well, Excel does limit cell length, no matter what's used to generate the spreadsheet. Looks like the CLOB issue is a bug. The only suggestion is to use to_char() ... https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3120738

Comment: Putting more than 4000 characters into an Excel cell would probably result in something unreadable.